# Как лучше хранить данные

Tags: javascript

Приветствую всех и поздравляю с наступающим Новым годом)

Мой вопрос больше не как проблема, а как просьба рекомендации.

Предположим, у меня есть большой набор различных цитат, к которым я буду обращаться через выбор рандомной из них.

Мне нужно использовать JSON, воспользоваться лишь массивом или есть какая-то другая, более верная альтернатива?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Воспользоваться массивом объектов, который будет сохранен в файле формата JSON с подгрузкой по AJAX?

Comment: А как часто выводятся клиенту эти цитаты и за какое время весь объем цитат показывается пользователю ? Как попадает этот массив клиенту ? Может было бы более выгодным отдавать клиенту по одной цитате с сервера, что бы не гнать весь объем

Comment: При загрузке страницы одна неизменяемая цитата до следующей перезагрузки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько большой? JSON [с вакансиями по Angular в Москве](https://api.hh.ru/vacancies?text=Angular&area=1) загружается за долю секунды.

```
<script async>
(async function() {
    console.time('Fetch big json');
    await fetch('https://api.hh.ru/vacancies?text=Angular&area=1');
    console.timeEnd('Fetch big json'); // Fetch big json: 673.172119140625ms
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Прошел год, но все равно спасибо за помощь в начале пути)